# AngularJS global optional hash parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, ngroute

How can I get/check the following url parameters with AngularJS?

`public/#/?var=test`

`public/#/new?var=test`

`public/#/statistics?var=test`

I'm using `ng-route` to route `/`, `/new`, ... to the concerning Controller.

How can I access the `var` parameter in a global controller.
I would like to use that optional parameter to show/hide a modal dialog triggered from a global controller. It should be independed of any route.

How can I achieve the goal?

Comment: $location is what you're looking for  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$location`:

```
app.module("my-app").controller(["$location", function($location){
  this.myVar = $location.search().var;
  // or
  this.myVar = $location.$$search.var;
}]);
```